# Running multiple legacy Windows applications in virtual environments

Tags: virtualization

I have a legacy Windows application (no source code) that does something with files in a given directory say C:\Pickup  The directory path is hard coded into the application and cannot be changed. If I run multiple instances of this application, the instances will compete for the same files in C:\Pickup which is not good.

This application does not have a GUI. I launch it from Task Scheduler many times a day and it runs from 1 minutes to say 20 minutes depending on the number of files it needs to process in C:\Pickup

I am wondering if there is easy to use virtualization technology that will allow me to launch instances of this application in some virtual space where each instance gets its own C:\Pickup folder?

EDIT 1: I am thinking of a solution like IE uses for plug-ins (ActiveX controls) that run inside of it. Somehow when the plug-in accesses the file system, it gets it's own view of the file system. Does anyone know how IE does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just spin up a series of VM's with something like virtual box. Create a share and mount as D:\ on all of the VM's, then run a batch  script to copy the files from your share to C:\Pickup.